# mySQL - ¿Se puede hacer algo parecido a INDEX + MATCH?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos días,

Necesito actualizar datos de forma masiva en tablas mySQL.
Lo que tengo:

```
Tabla1 => Donde quiero actualizar datos, tengo 2 columnas, ID1 y VIEJOTEXTO.

Tabla2 => Una tabla con 2 columnas, ID1 y ID3.

Tabla3 => Tabla donde tengo que coger el dato, 2 columnas, ID3 y NUEVO TEXTO.
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer el `UPDATE` en la `Tabla1` para que, en función de la relación que existe en la `Tabla2`, me actualice el `"VIEJOTEXTO"(Tabla1)` por el `"NUEVOTEXTO"(Tabla3)`?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Nicolau. No te olvides de incluir en tu pregunta lo que has intentado. Probablemente alguna sentencia `UPDATE`.

Comment: (sorry, no puedo editar la pregunta)
He probado el siguiente código para utilizar 2 tablas, pero no soy capaz de adaptarla a 3 columnas:

UPDATE TABLE2
       JOIN TABLE1
       ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
SET    TABLE2.OLDTEXT = TABLE1.NEWTEXT;

Comment: Deberías poder editar tu propia pregunta sin problemas usando el enlace `editar` debajo de tu pregunta. En cuanto a tu pregunta, la explicación está un poco confusa. ¿Cuales son esas 3 columnas de las que hablas? ¿Deseas poner al día solamente `oldtext` a `newtext`, o algo mas? ¿Cual es la forma de relacionar las 2 tablas, solo con los IDs, o con otras columnas también?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas!

Dí con una solución, aunque no sé si es la más optima (but it works!).

Para relacionar 2 o más tablas creamos una consulta agrupando todas las tablas indicando la relación entre cada una de ellas y con ello podemos asignar el valor de un campo a otro campo, como si estuvieran en la misma tabla.

Código para el ejemplo dispuesto en la pregunta:

```
UPDATE `tabla1` JOIN `tabla2` ON tabla1.id1 = tabla2.id1 JOIN `tabla3` ON tabla2.id3 = tabla3.id3 SET tabla1.viejotexto = tabla3.nuevotexto;
```

Mil gracias a todos, y espero que sirva de ayuda a más gente ;)